# Java - Factory and Strategy Patterns with Generics

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement a Strategy + Factory pattern using generics. The goal is to return to a client class an implementation of the interface DocumentDao that can deal with a type T extends Document, so I've multiple Dao interface extending DocumentDao for different subtypes of Document.

Here is my code:

```
public class Document { ... }

public class DocumentA extends Document { ... }

public class DocumentB extends Document { ... }

public interface DocumentDao<T extends Document> {
   public void update(T document);
}

public interface DocumentADao<DocumentA> {}

public interface DocumentDaoFactory {
   public <T extends Document> DocumentDao<T> getDaoInstance(Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Then I try to use the Factory:

```
private <T extends Document> void someMethod(T document) {
   ...
   DocumentDao<T> documentDao = this.documentDaoFactory.getDaoInstance(document.getClass());
   documentDao.update(document);
   ...
}
```

But the compiler complaints about the getDaoInstance() call:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DocumentDao<? extends AbstractGDriveDocument<?>> to DocumentDao<T>
```

How to deal with this situation?
How can I obtain a similar solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `getClass` is returning a `Class<?>`, which is appropriate for the API; it would not know what specific `Class` instance to bring back.  Additionally, your type bound is incorrect and invalid in your method.

To fix this, you would need to change two things:

- In your `DocumentDaoFactory` method, change the bound to be appropriate.

  ```
  <T extends Document> DocumentDao<T> getDaoInstance(Class<T> clazz);
  ```
- In your use of `getDaoInstance`, perform an unchecked cast to `Class<T>`.

  ```
  DocumentDao<T> documentDao = this.documentDaoFactory.getDaoInstance((Class<T>) document.getClass());
  ```

The way that your types are bound should give you back the instances you care about, without getting any runtime errors.

Comment: Sorry for the first error, it was just an oversight (in my real code it was correct), so i will update the question.
The second point solved my problem, thank you very much.